# How to return to the beginning of the code after it turns false?

Tags: python, loops, while-loop

I am doing [this](http://reeborg.ca/docs/begin_py_en/while.html) tutorial.

Basically my problem is, after front_is_clear is false, it runs jump_over_hurdle, and stops.

```
from my_lib import *

while front_is_clear():
    move()

if not front_is_clear():
    jump_over_hurdle()
```

How can I get it to return back to doing

```
while front_is_clear():
    move()
```

Also I want the program to end once it reaches its goal. So some how I need to implement..

```
if at_goal():
    done()
```

Comment: When it should reach at_goal() in ur code ?

Comment: Is it this way: front_is_clear=>move=>not front_is_clear=> move=> at goal ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just use another while loop like

```
from my_lib import *

# well, maybe not `not at_goal()` since it only check it after
# the below code finish running, it would be better to use `while True`
# and find a better way to implement the at_goal()

while not at_goal():
    while front_is_clear():
        move()

    if not front_is_clear():
        jump_over_hurdle()

done()
```

Comment: Oh wow it was so simple! thanks, never thought of using two loops like that.

Comment: I added another if at_goal(): done() after while front_is_clear in the first block

Comment: You can use while True .. if at_goal(): break .. Just to enter the loop at the beginning.

Comment: @user3378649 that not much different from putting it at the end if you think about it, in fact, it not much different from `while not at_goal()`

Comment: @RyanThacker you might also need to add that `if at_goal` in the `while front_is_clear` loop too, unless the goal is something that make the front `not clear` if you know what i mean

Answer (score 0):

A nested loop isn't necessary. In the original code, the while loop is redundant with the if-check; if you `move` repeatedly `while front_is_clear`, then of course it will not be the case that `front_is_clear` after the end of the loop (or else it would keep looping).

Really, what we want to do is repeatedly *either* move *or* jump until we reach the goal:

```
while not at_goal():
    if front_is_clear():
        move()
    else:
        jump_over_hurdle()
done()
```

This also avoids the problem from the original code of reaching the goal while in the middle of "moving to the next hurdle", because we check if we're at the goal after every step (be it a move or a jump).

Comment: @ryan-thacker this is the right way to do it, i suppose i should go to sleep if i am missing this kind of easy solution.